# how to stop pooling in angular5

Tags: typescript, observable, angular2-forms, angular-promise, angular5

service.ts:

```
   // Get all AgentLog log using pooling
     getAgentLogStream(): Promise<string> {
       const url = `${this.testCaseUrl}/logfile`;
       return  Observable
       .interval(5000).flatMap((i)=>
        this.http.get(url)
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => response.text())
       .catch(this.handleError));
}
```

component.ts:

```
getAgentLogStream1() {
    return this.AgentService.getAgentLogStream()
    .subscribe( agentLogStream => this.agentLogStream = agentLogStream
            , error => console.log(error));
}
```

I am using above code for service for making rest calls and corresponding component code.

Below is the code in same component to control pooled data:

```
 //To auto refresh the logs 
onChange( event ) {
    console.log( 'Event', event )
    if ( event.target.checked ) {
        this.getAgentLogStream1();
    } 
}
```

I am able to get periodically refreshed data,but unable to stop it even after navigating to other page.need help on how to stop if i navigate to other page or toggle though UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store subscription in some variable inside component:

```
this.streamSubscription = this.getAgentLogStream1();
```

Then if you want to cancel this subscription call:

```
streamSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Inside your component It'll look like this:

```
export class SomeComponent  {
  //...
  streamSubscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.streamSubscription = this.getAgentLogStream1();
  }

  getAgentLogStream1(): Promise<string> {
   return this.AgentService.getAgentLogStream()
     .subscribe(
       agentLogStream => this.agentLogStream = agentLogStream,
       error => console.log(error)
     );
  }

  functionToCallIfYouWantToCancelSubscription() {
    this.streamSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: so,do i need to remove subscription part from getAgentLogStream1() totally,can u please give more details(i renamed function and saved to avoid confusion),can u please provide little more code description ..

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if something is not clear